# branch.io loadRewards - Can't create handler inside thread that has not called Looper.prepare()

Tags: android, branch.io, referrals, android-looper

I am using `branch.io` for referrals. When I make a call to load the rewards using `loadRewards()`, I get the following exception:

```
Fatal Exception: java.lang.RuntimeException: Can't create handler inside thread that has not called Looper.prepare()
       at android.os.Handler.(Handler.java:204)
       at android.os.Handler.(Handler.java:118)
       at io.branch.referral.InstallListener.captureInstallReferrer(InstallListener.java:56)
       at io.branch.referral.Branch.registerAppInit(Branch.java:2340)
       at io.branch.referral.Branch.initializeSession(Branch.java:2298)
       at io.branch.referral.Branch.initUserSessionInternal(Branch.java:1286)
       at io.branch.referral.Branch.handleNewRequest(Branch.java:2450)
       at io.branch.referral.Branch.loadRewards(Branch.java:1699)
       at com.musicmuni.riyaz.data.AppDataRepositoryImpl.getReferralCredits(AppDataRepositoryImpl.java:2926)
  .......
```

Looking the error message, it seems that the call required to be triggered from a UI thread. But since this is a network call, this seems unusual. Is there anything that I am missing?

Answer (score 0):

this crash can only happen when you call initSession from a non-UI thread. You are creating the handler inside the thread that has not called Looper.prepare(), so can you please make sure the initSession is happening on the main thread?